Grouping handler is not expiring message groups
I am using the ActiveMQ Artemis (2.38.0) feature 'Message groups' in my application and I am seeing that the number of groups I have continues to grow.
I have checked the configuration reference and also seen this post.
Based on this above information I'm under the impression that I can create a 'grouping-handler' that will automatically expire my message groups after a set of time.
However, I am not seeing my group count decrease, and the listGroupsAsJSON() operation is still showing me all the groups long after the given timeout period.
My broker.xml contains this nested in the core tag:
  <grouping-handler name="grouping-handler">
     <type>LOCAL</type>
     <group-timeout>120000</group-timeout>
     <reaper-period>60000</reaper-period>
  </grouping-handler>

What am I doing wrong here?
